# how to return value from this public function?

Tags: java, android, return

Examle below must return `user.photo_100` (and `user.photo_100` response String, I logged it), but var `wallPostUserAvatar` set null. Looks like I missed something, but I can't find it out.

```
public class WallPostExtends {
    private String wallPostUserAvatar;

    public String getUserPhotoLink(int user_id){
        //Prepare request for userName and photo
        final VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.USER_ID, user_id, VKApiConst.FIELDS, "photo_100"));

        request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                super.onComplete(response);
                //Work with UserName and photo response
                VKApiUserFull user = ((VKList<VKApiUserFull>) response.parsedModel).get(0);
                wallPostUserAvatar = user.photo_100;

            }
        });
        Log.d("photo link: ", wallPostUserAvatar); //Here is NULL. What am I doing wrong?
        return wallPostUserAvatar; //How to return here "user.photo_100" ?
    }
}
```

Comment: `onComplete` called after `return wallPostUserAvatar;` you must handle listener in where you want get data, pass listener to this function and use that instead of `new VKRequest.VKRequestListener()`

Comment: is it a sync or async call?

Comment: yeah, it's async call...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i came to know the reason why `wallPostUserAvatar` is null , because the you are assigning the value in `onComplete()` and the execution flow is not how you think, the log you printed will be executed first and then depends on what is happening in `executeWithListener()` will execute after.

I have a solution for this, i will share with you.
You can use **callback** mechanism here.
A typical example would be using **Interface**

```
 public interface Callbacks {
       public void successCallback(String response);
       public void failCallback(String response);
}
```

Then you can use this interface as follows:

```
 public void getUserPhotoLink(int user_id,final Callbacks callback){

 request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
              callbacks.failCallback("fail");
            }

           @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                super.onComplete(response);
                //Your code
               callback.successCallback(user.photo_100);

            }
```

Then you can call  you function getUserPhotoLink() as

```
getUserPhotoLink(userid value,new Callbacks() {
    @Override
    public void successCallback(String success) {

        //You will get your desired result here
     }
    @Override
    public void failCallback(String fail) {

    });
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: change `public String getUserPhotoLink` to `public void getUserPhotoLink`, we don't need return any thing

Comment: Just implement you own `VKRequestListener`is IS a callback already.. Just implement the interface the way you want it.. Your suggested answer implements two interfaces which are equivalent..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the VKApi, but it looks like its an asynchronous call based on the name and the fact you pass in a listener.  That means you CANT return the string, because you won't have it until the asynchronous call completes.  Instead you'd need to do any processing of it in onComplete.

Answer (score 0):

In short:
Sorry to tell you, but you cannot return any value right there.

The `VKRequestListener` is called asynchronously, while the method returns immediately.

You will have to find a more suitable solution for this, like handing over the object you want to make the String accessable to and call a set-Method in the onComplete block.

Answer (score -1):

If this is not being run on the UI thread, try putting a `while(wallPostUserAvatar!=null);` after the call to the log function.  This would work because, as is, you probably have a race condition between the return and the API request and the return statement will almost always win that race.

Comment: You should absolutely not do this if it is being run on the UI thread, though, as it will lock up the UI.